# IBMMQDotnet client retry mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, message-queue

Hi everyone i am completely new to queues and especialy to IBMMQDotnet cleint library. Currently my application trying to send DTO object to the queue and sometimes it could faailed for various reasons like exception occuring or network issue. Is there any retrie mechanism ?i would like to implement retry mechansim, i tried to google it but could not found any example. Bellow is the current code

```
                if (!TryConnectToQueueManager())
                {
                   return;
                }
               using var destination = GetMqObjectForWrite(message.Destination, message.DestinationType);

                var mqMessage = new MQMessage
                {
                    Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING,
                    CharacterSet = 1208
                };

                if (message.Headers?.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var (key, value) in message.Headers)
                    {
                        mqMessage.SetStringProperty(key, value);
                    }
                }

                mqMessage.WriteString(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message.Data));

                destination.Put(mqMessage);

                destination.Close();
```

Comment: why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653972/high-cpu-consumption-ibm-mq-read-messages, I wanted to provide an official answer for you assuming my suggestions worked,  I think it was a valid question and world be valuable to others in the future in the same situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM MQ provides a feature called as Client Auto Reconnect.You could refer the following KC page [Client Auto Reconnect](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=programs-automatic-client-reconnection-in-net)

If there is a connection failure because of the network issue, the IBM MQ client will try to re-establish a connection to the Queue Manager for a specific time period(which is configurable) before throwing an exception to the application

You could refer to the sample "SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut" & "SimpleClientAutoReconnectGet" which are available as part of the client installation.

Comment: sorry but i could not find any info regarding SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut is thislibrary class or what ?

Comment: One question also , how can i define how many times i want to reconnect and the the interval of  reconnect attempts ?

Comment: I was referring to SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut sample which is available only with IBM MQ Client installation.You can set the reconnect timeout property

Comment: I think there is no property where you can set "how many times to reconnect" or "Reconnect Interval". You can only set for how long you want to try reconnection attempts using Reconnect Timeout

Comment: We encountered this kind of case also, what if we did not even started to connect queue manager and connection is lost, but the message should be sent, what can we do ?I mean how to handle cases when we did not establish initial connection with queue manager ? Is there any built in solutions in the library ?

Comment: You could use CONNECTIONNAMELIST where you could specify the list of host(port) combinations that you want your application to connect.It will start with the first host in the list and then if it is not able to connect,it would try to connect to the second host in the list

Comment: By saying combination hosts you meant multiple instances of queue manager deployed to the server ?